# French accents within an email address

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

Looking for help on having french accents within an email address.

Dummy email for this example: aéf@gmail.com

Now since Salesforce Marketing Cloud does not support that address upon import, is there a workaround to this?

In the example above, should we be adjust that character to be just "e"?

Comment: According to [RFC5322](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-3.4.1) it looks like the "local part" of an email address should only be built from ASCII characters, and this is probably the standard applied by Salesforce. Mapping an accented character to the closest ASCII character may or may not actually work - it depends on the recipient mail server and how it looks up mailboxes.

Comment: Based on the Winter 20 release notes, this _should_ be coming if it's not there yet.  Are there any critical updates in your org around emails? See here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?language=en_US&type=1&mode=1&id=000350508

Comment: Those are Salesforce CRM Winter 20 release notes and aren't relevant to Marketing Cloud.

Comment: Seems like the current standard for internationalisation of email addresses is RFC6532. It definitely allows for UTF-8 aliases and domains... https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6532. Probably one for Ideas and the Product Team to look at implementing.

Comment: There is a 10 year old "idea" already. Not sure if that is good or bad news for you though :D

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000GsDZAA0


Cloudpages / smart capture use this regex for email: ^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$ - source: https://mc.s50.exacttarget.com/CloudPages/lib/jquery.validator.js 
it does not support your character (check via regexstorm.net) - probably that is also what Marketing Cloud as a whole will do. I'm not aware of a workaround.